# Вызов несуществующего конструктора без параметров супер класса android.widget.Button

Tags: java, android

В созданном мной классе имплементирую интерфейс `Parcelable`. Android Studio генерирует реализованные методы интерфейса, в котором использует приватный конструктор с параметром типа класс `Parcel`. Именно в данном конструкторе и требуется вызов конструктора класса родителя.

Как решить эту проблему?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LvlButton extends Button implements Parcelable{

    private int size;
    private String number;

    public LvlButton(Context context, String number , int size) {
        super(context);

        this.number = number;
        this.size = size;

        setText(number);
        setWidth(size);
        setHeight(size);
    }
```

Вот что он пишет в следующем конструкторе:

```
// There is no default constructor available in 'android.widget.Button

    protected LvlButton(Parcel in) {
        size = in.readInt();
        number = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<LvlButton> CREATOR = new Creator<LvlButton>() {
        @Override
        public LvlButton createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new LvlButton(in);
        }

        @Override
        public LvlButton[] newArray(int size) {
            return new LvlButton[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(size);
        parcel.writeString(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем Вам Parcelable для кнопки? Вы что-то не то делаете.

Comment: мне нужно передавать в фрагмент коллекцию созданных мной кнопок. делаю это с помощью  Bundle.putParcelable ArrayList()

Comment: попробую спросить еще раз. Зачем может понадобиться передавать кнопки между контроллерами? это какая то дикая идея. Вы лучше задайте вопрос о самой проблеме, которую вам надо решить, а не костыльте невероятные велосипеды, то что вы пытаетесь делать настолько неприемлемо в нормальной разработке, что нельзя даже слов подобрать ...

Comment: по эпичности происходящего ваша идея примерно равна тому, что вас попросили отправить 10 скриншотов и вот вы берете 10 ноутбуков, каждый из которых содержит нужное изображение на экране, пакуете их в коробку и уже готовы отправить, но теперь решаете проблему, как при вытаскивании из коробки эти ноутбуки показали бы нужное изображение. Согласитесь, что и сама идея и появившееся в связи с ее реализацией проблема далеко за гранью здравого смысла, но именно этим вы и занимаетесь

Comment: то что я костылю велосипеды эт понятно ведь я только начал заниматься программированием). Подскажите как тогда реализовать задачу : есть главное активити в котором хочу переходить между фрагменты, содержащие в себе кнопки, при нажатии на кнопки "вперед","назад".А кнопи которые находятся в фрагментах вызывают соответствующие активити

Comment: нет, это не понятно. раз не знаете, как сделать - найдите правильное решение, есть документация, книги по разработке, ресурсы вроде этого, но это точно не повод придумывать неворятные собственные решения. все типовые задачи уже решены и есть практики, самому что то придумывать уже редко приходится, особенно новичкам, достаточно просто прочитать. Задайте новый вопрос и в нем опишите, какая именно задача, что должно происходить и тд, как можно подробнее. из вашего комментария уже ясно, что делаете вы все совершенно не правильно и в рамках этого вопроса ответ будет неуместным.

Answer (score 2):

Механизмы парселизации и сериализации не передают объекты, а снимают их параметры и на другом конце создают новые объекты с теми же параметрами. То есть Вы делаете лишнюю и бессмысленную работу. Вместо этого нужно создавать кнопки непосредственно во фрагменте, а передавать туда данные, для вставки в эти кнопки (текст, ссылка на картинку, цвет фона, ... - всё, что неизвестно заранее и нельзя определить в самом фрагменте)

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуй вам стоит решить проблему передачи кнопок иначе. Для того, чтобы Parcelable заработал он должен быть имплиментирован самим Button, что по-понятным причинам не возможно. Создайте модель MyButton, проимплиментите ее от Parcelable. Далее передавайте список из этих моделей в нужный вам класс. Если нужно передать обработчик, то реализуйте это через интефейс. В текущем варианте никак работать не будет, извините.

Comment: пожалуй стоит акцентировать на том, что передавать кнопки между контроллерами вообще крайне неудачная затея, а не пытаться ее как то воплотить в жизнь. особенно учитывая то, что работать такое "изобретение" (идея передавать виджеты) в любом случае вряд ли будет –

Comment: ну, иногда передача происходит не только между контроллерами. Допустим, у вас recyclerView из кнопок. В таком случае, "передачу кнопок" все-равно придется как-то реализовать .В моей небольшой практике такая потребность один раз возникла (создавал кастомную клавиатуру по специализированному предмету)